# Convert sample JSON to nested JSON array using JOLT Transformation

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I am facing a problem, transforming flat JSON to the nested JSON using jolt transformation. And I am very new to jolt Transformation. Input and output detail is given below.

My input:

```json
[
  {
    "policyNo": 1,
    "lProdCode": 500,
    "name": "Prasad",
    "id": "10",
    "Age": "56"
  },
  {
    "policyNo": 1,
    "lProdCode": 500,
    "name": "Mahapatra",
    "id": "101",
    "Age": "56"
  },
  {
    "policyNo": 2,
    "lProdCode": 500,
    "name": "Pra",
    "id": "109",
    "Age": "56"
  },
  {
    "policyNo": 3,
    "lProdCode": 400,
    "name": "Pra",
    "id": "108",
    "Age": "56"
  },
  {
    "policyNo": 1,
    "lProdCode": 500,
    "name": "Pra",
    "id": "108",
    "Age": "56"
  }
]
```

expected output

```json
[
  {
    "policyNo": 1,
    "lProdCode": 500,
    "beneficiaries": [
      {
        "name": "Prasad",
        "id": "10900629001",
        "Age": "56"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mahapatra",
        "id": "10900629001",
        "Age": "56"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pra",
        "id": "108",
        "Age": "56"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "policyNo": 2,
    "lProdCode": 500,
    "beneficiaries": [
      {
        "name": "Pra",
        "id": "10900629001",
        "Age": "56"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "policyNo": 3,
    "lProdCode": 400,
    "beneficiaries": [
      {
        "name": "Pra",
        "id": "108",
        "Age": "56"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principally you need to group by `policyNo` attribute along with generating a new list(`beneficiaries`) for the attributes other than `policyNo`&`lProdCode`. That might be handled within a **shift** transformation. Then add three more steps to prune the roughnesses stems from the first transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "policyNo": "@(1,policyNo).&",
        "lProdCode": "@(1,policyNo).&",
        "*": "@(1,policyNo).beneficiaries[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "policyNo": "ONE",
        "lProdCode": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Please let me know if any resource/URL guide me to learn JOLT JSON.

Comment: Hi @GouriMahapatra , sure, I frequently use [this demo](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) which is very helpful to develop my jolt level and [this](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) might be a good tutorial, especially the part which introducing the transformations under the Documentation subtitle. Best wishes.

Comment: Ozhan Thanks your support

Comment: Ozhan
I want to rename "policyNo" field to p_cd and lProdCode field to l_cd.
How I will modify this JOLT?

Comment: Hi @GouriMahapatra , then you need to convert `"policyNo": "@(1,policyNo).&"` to `"policyNo": "@(1,policyNo).p_cd"` and `"lProdCode": "@(1,policyNo).&"` to `"lProdCode": "@(1,policyNo).l_cd"` within the **shift** *along with* `policyNo` to `p_cd` and `lProdCode` to `l_cd` with the **cardinality** transformations.

Comment: Hi, @Ozhan I have a question, I found if one field is having a null value then that field missing after JOLT, how I will make it blank or "".

Comment: Hi @GouriMahapatra , can you give an example how a field to be null?